# Batch ping monitor not writing to log

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I wrote this script to `ping` different POS devices in order to monitor downtime. In writing this, the `echo %tdstamp1% SN-%storenum%-DEVICE MONITOR SERVICE STARTED>> %LOGFILE%` line works and writes the message to the log that the device monitor has started. The rest of the script does not write to the log when a device goes offline. I can test this at will by manually rebooting devices, and if I turn `@echo off` to `@echo on`, I can see the script stop on the device that is offline, but don't see any errors and doesn't write to the log.

```
@echo off
set storenum=%computername:~6,2%
set pos1=10.6.%storenum%.20
set pos2=10.6.%storenum%.21
set pinpad1=10.6.%storenum%.15
set pinpad2=10.6.%storenum%.16
set tdstamp1=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
set logfile="C:\Company Name\Device Monitor\Log\DeviceStatLog.log"
echo %tdstamp1% SN-%storenum%-DEVICE MONITOR SERVICE STARTED>> %LOGFILE%

:loop
set tdstamp=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
ping -n 1 %pos1% >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%
echo.>> %LOGFILE%
ping -n 1 %pos2% >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%
echo.>> %LOGFILE%
ping -n 1 %pinpad1% >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%
echo.>> %LOGFILE%
ping -n 1 %pinpad2% >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%
echo.>> %LOGFILE%
choice /N /T 5 /D Y >nul
goto loop
```

Per Stephan's suggestion:  In attempting this, I still get nothing in the log except for the "DEVICE MONITOR STARTED" message. I also tried `ping -n 1 %pos1% >nul | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%`
But this made all devices appear offline.

Also removed

```
`echo. >> %LOGFILE%`
```

as it spammed in the logfile creating whitespace.

```
@echo off
set storenum=%computername:~6,2%
set pos1=10.6.%storenum%.20
set pos2=10.6.%storenum%.21
set pos3=10.6.%storenum%.22
set pinpad1=10.6.%storenum%.15
set pinpad2=10.6.%storenum%.16
set pinpad3=10.6.%storenum%.17
set tdstamp1=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
set logfile="C:\Company Name\Device Monitor\Log\DeviceStatLog.log"
echo %tdstamp1%_SN-%storenum%-DEVICE MONITOR SERVICE STARTED>> %LOGFILE%

:loop

set tdstamp=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%

ping -n 1 %pos1% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pos2% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pos3% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS3 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pinpad1% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pinpad2% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pinpad3% | find "TTL=" || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD3 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

choice /N /T 5 /D Y >nul
goto loop
```

Comment: Ping probably returns something like `Reply from <localhost>; Destination host unreachable.`. Which *is* a response, so no error, so no `||`. Switch to `ping ... |find "TTL=" || ...`

Comment: @Stephan That does make sense, I'm modifying the script and testing now!

Comment: @Stephan Please see edit to main post with new code block. I tried your suggestion although this did not work. Maybe I did this incorrectly?

Comment: When you redirect the output of `ping` to `nul` *before* `find` gets to see it - what do you think `find` can find? `ping -n 1 %pos1% | find "TTL=" >nul || echo`...`

Comment: @Stephan This is working now! Thank you so much for your help and thank you for helping me understand!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set storenum=%computername:~6,2%
set pos1=10.6.%storenum%.20
set pos2=10.6.%storenum%.21
set pinpad1=10.6.%storenum%.15
set pinpad2=10.6.%storenum%.16
set tdstamp1=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
set logfile="C:\Company Name\Device Monitor\Log\DeviceStatLog.log"
echo %tdstamp1%_SN-%storenum%-DEVICE MONITOR SERVICE STARTED>> %LOGFILE%

:loop


set tdstamp=%date:~4,2%/%date:~7,2%/%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%

ping -n 1 %pos1% | find "TTL=" >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pos2% | find "TTL=" >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-POS2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pinpad1% | find "TTL=" >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD1 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

ping -n 1 %pinpad2% | find "TTL=" >nul || echo %tdstamp% SN-%storenum%-PINPAD2 OFFLINE >> %LOGFILE%

choice /N /T 9 /D Y >nul
goto loop
```